EntityManager Error in Spring Boot project when using h2 database , error is occuring when using the data.sql file add in src/main/resources
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of file [C:\Users\KARAN\OneDrive\Desktop\SPJ\JPASPRINGBOOT\target\classes\data.sql]: insert into alien values(101,'karan')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at com.example.demo.JpaspringbootApplication.main(JpaspringbootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of file [C:\Users\KARAN\OneDrive\Desktop\SPJ\JPASPRINGBOOT\target\classes\data.sql]: insert into alien values(101,'karan')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of file [C:\Users\KARAN\OneDrive\Desktop\SPJ\JPASPRINGBOOT\target\classes\data.sql]: insert into alien values(101,'karan')
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:102) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:77) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into alien values(101,'karan') [42104-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8051) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8035) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8024) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7990) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1540) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:719) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:592) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:564) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:483) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:639) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:559) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1166) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:245) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:231) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 27 common frames omitted

solve the error occuring in spring boot project

Table "ALIEN" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement: looks like you didn't setup tables that you are referencing in your data.sql

This could be because of the table name being in uppercase
Append DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE to the datasource url in properties fil.
